# How to enter a space in the minibuffer instead of completing a word?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to print from `dired-mode` by using `P`. This works fine for the default print command I have set up via `lpr-switches`, but I often want to edit the command. For example, if `P` suggests `lpr`, I would like to add `-o number-up=2`. The problem is that this contains a space after `-o` and hitting the space bar gives me `No match`. How can one adjust the `lpr` (or other commands facing the same problem)?

Comment: It might be helpful to change the title of your question, to make it easier to find for people with a similar problem. Perhaps something like: "enter a space in the minibuffer instead of completing a word"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the mini-buffer, `space` is bound to a completion command. If you want to enter an actual ' ', you need to quote it: `C-q <space>`. This comes up a lot for me, so I've bound `M-<space>` to enter a literal space in the minibuffer:

EDIT: following phils comment, the following code snippet is really pointless. You can get the desired behaviour with `M-space` without any keybindings.

```el
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map "\M- " 
    (lambda () (interactive) (insert " ")))
```

Comment: These days (at least) `M-SPC` is bound to `just-one-space` which is often very useful when reformatting text, but also means you can use this answer *without* needing the code.

Comment: @phils I can't believe I missed that when I put this together. The completion used to drive me crazy in bibtex-mode, and I thought I was being really clever using `M-space` since it wasn't useful in the minibuffer. Except that it is! D'oh.

Comment: I also tried `M-space`, but that triggered a default command on Ubuntu: Some menu pops up in the current window, showing "Minimize, Maximmize,...", but working with `C-q` is fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can also bind `SPC` to `self-insert-command` in each of the minibuffer keymaps.  Then you do not need to use `C-q`.

(There is no reason in the 21st century for `SPC` in the minibuffer to complete.  Emacs finally got rid of this vestige for file-name completion, but it has not yet wised up wrt other kinds of completion.  ***No*** printable character should be bound to a command that completes --- they should all self-insert.  Not being able to insert a `?` or `SPC` without using `C-q` is archaic.)

Comment: Hi Drew, can you be more specific what you mean by "each of the minibuffer keymaps", please?

Comment: These are minibuffer completion keymaps (I should have added the qualifier "completion", since you want this only for completion keymaps): `minibuffer-local-completion-map`, `minibuffer-local-must-match-map`, `minibuffer-local-filename-completion-map`, `minibuffer-local-filename-must-match-map`.  For recent Emacs versions you can probably forget about modifying the last two.

Comment: Hi Drew, the best I could come up with based on your description is `(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map (kbd " ") 'self-insert-command)` and the corresponding for the other functions. But I still get `No match` :-(

Comment: The printed form of the space char is `SPC`, not " ". Use `(kbd "SPC")` instead of `(kbd " ")`.

Comment: thanks, Drew, that worked :-). I'll test in the near future if that has any unexpected side-effects.